# List<> Versus IEnumerable<>, when defining a new class or a new viewmodel class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have defined a new ViewModel class as follow:-

```
public class myviewmodel
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

but I can also defined it as

```
public class myviewmodel
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

and this can also happen if I want to create a new model class;
So what are the differences between the two appraches?
BR

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from `List<T>` in favor of `ICollection<T>` if possible: using "plain" list reveals too much about your implementation. `IEnumerable<T>` is a good choice as it gives you best flexibility in choosing the actual implementation, but it may not be sufficient if you need to find out the number of elements available to you without enumerating through the collection.

Comment: What's wrong with revealing too much about your implementation?

Comment: @Extragorey It works directly against the goal of encapsulation.

Comment: Right, the wording just made it sound like you were talking about source confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `IList<Question>`.

> what are the differences between the two appraches?

The `IEnumerable<>` is more general (but also less functional). You can assign it from any Linq query without worrying about the actual list type.

The `List<>` version is more closely defined, you may have to convert to a List before you can assign it. It does give you more functionality.

You probably want something like `IList<QuestionViewModel>`

Comment: What is practical benefit of `IList` againts `List` ?

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` is more abstract and is generally preferred to `List` or `IList` if possible. Simply because it's an interface and you have more implementation possibilities.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347172/explanation-why-ienumerable-is-more-efficient-then-a-list).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In general you should prefer to return an interface such as `ICollection`, `IList` or `IEnumerable` as it gives you the option to change the actual implementation without breaking the code (as long as the implementation adheres to the interface contract).

Now as for which interface you should choose depends and what you need to do. For example if it should be possible to add items to the collection via `Questions.Add()` then you can't use an `IEnumerable` as it does not offer such an method.

Answer (score 0):

I think others have already answered well, I would just like to add one thing:

`IList` is not always bad as opposed to `ICollection` as it should represent information that is already on memory (thus providing indexing and the `Count` property). In that case (information on memory) the `ICollection` would not be so good as a call to `Count()` might iterate over a collection even if the iterator is not lazy.